# Creating table,queries and relations between the tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, scripting, relation

I need to create 4tables(Products,Customers,Orders,Order Items). Products hold name and price. Customers hold name. Orders hold customer, date and set of order items. Order items hold order, product and quantity. All tables should have auto-increment primary key – id.
After creating the table I need to execute different scripts and I cannot understand why when I run this script:

```
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES (1,'2015-02-13 13:47:04'), (2,'2015-02-14 22:03:44'), (3,'2015-02-18 09:22:01'), (4,'2015-02-11 20:17:18');
```

I am getting this error:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

I create the table in this way:

```
Create table Orders
(
OrdersID int not null,
Customer varchar(50),
date date,
Set_Of_Order_Items varchar(50),
primary key(OrdersID)
)
```

Any suggestions why I am receiving this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want insert only some columns you must  explicitally indicate these columns

```
 INSERT INTO Orders (OrdersID , date)  
 VALUES (1,'2015-02-13 13:47:04'), 
 (2,'2015-02-14 22:03:44'), 
 (3,'2015-02-18 09:22:01'), 
 (4,'2015-02-11 20:17:18');
```